# Find the open interval on which $x^{1/3}-9$ is increasing/decreasing

Tags: calculus

Consider the following function

$$f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{3}} - 9$$

How can I find the open interval on which the function is increasing or decreasing?

a. I know the critical points are $(0,-9)$

b. I know that the interval is not decreasing.

c. I know that by applying first derivative test to identify the relative extremum. (In this case no extrema).

All I cannot figure out is: in which interval the function is increasing?

Comment: What do you mean with the critical points being $(0,-9)$?

Comment: Wrong typing: f(x)=x^1/3 -9

Comment: That's what it currently is: $\sqrt[3]x=x^{1/3}$.

Comment: Did you mean $\displaystyle x^{(1/3)-9}$? If so, you should have used parentheses.

Comment: In what intervals is $f'(x)\ge0$? Note $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but $f$ is continuous there (I'm assuming you want $f(x)=x^{1/3}-9$). This should be all you need...

Comment: Yes thanks. However I have to find the open interval which the function is increasing?

Comment: It's increasing on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

To find where a function is increasing or decreasing, we look at the first derivative:
$$f(x) = x^{1/3} - 9\\
f'(x) = \frac{x^{-2/3}}{3}$$

We set the derivative equal to zero:
$$\frac{x^{-2/3}}{3} = 0$$
$$x^{-2/3} = 0$$
$$\frac{1}{x} = 0$$

Critical points come in two categories: *stationary* and *singular*.  *Stationary* points are where the first derivative is equal to zero; *singular* points are where it is undefined.
Note that $\frac{1}{x} \ne 0$ for any $x$; thus, there are *no stationary points*!
However, the function $f'(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$, so there *is a singular point* at $x=0$.

Now, we test $f'(x)$ to see if it is positive or negative on either side of the origin:
$$f(-1) = \frac{1}{3},\qquad f(1) = \frac{1}{3}$$

Thus, the first derivative is positive for *all x values*, except $x=0$ (where it is undefined).  This tells us that the function is increasing on the interval $(-\infty, 0)$ and on $(0, \infty)$.  But what about at $x=0$?

As $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, $f$ is increasing on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  So, our final interval is $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Thank you. My first answer was Increasing at (0,Infinity) which was wrong.

Comment: And (-Infinity,0) is wrong to.

Comment: yes that's correct thanks

Comment: Well I think every software has deferent ways for the answer.

Comment: Very nice now. +1 (Sorry to have nitpicked.)

Comment: @DavidMitra I'm glad you nitpicked! :)  I wouldn't want to leave something wrong in on my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Sara, your answer $(-\infty , 0)$ is not wrong, since it is true that the function is increasing in this interval. The same holds for $(0 , + \infty)$.
The answer must be $(- \infty , + \infty )$ only if the question was to find the **largest** interval where the function is increasing or decreasing :)

Comment: Thanks. (-infinity,+infinity) was a correct answer.